# Where can I find Firefox's default CSS?

Tags: css, firefox, settings, default

I want to use the same typeface for some <div> as Firefox's <pre>. Apparently this is not Courier New; they look different. Where can I find the file with all of Firefox's default CSS? I've looked in the installation folder, but I can't find a single CSS file there, nor in the subfolders.

Comment: Install [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/), create a blank HTML page, enable Firebug from the "Web Developer menu" and click on the "HTML" tab. You'll see the default CSS styles applied to the page there (in the "computed" panel)

Comment: it's inside a jar file. Not sure what the exact path is, but it should be somewhere under `chrome://browser/content/`.

Comment: Not it, but an example: `chrome://browser/content/browser.css`

Comment: @OneTrickPony Firefox's default css does _not_ show up in FireBug.

Comment: @Mooseman: Did you try it? It's supposed to show the default styles applied to the page, so if you throw a page without your own CSS styles, you'll see the defaults. OP can create a `<pre>` element, click on it in Firebug, and all CSS props that are used on it will be listed

Comment: Firefox's user interface can be modified by editing the userChrome.css and userContent.css files in ~/.mozilla/firefox/<profile_dir>/chrome/ (profile_dir is of the form hash.name, where the hash is an 8 character, seemingly random string and the profile name is usually default).
Note: The chrome/ folder and userChrome.css/userContent.css files may not necessarily exist, so you have to create them.